# GoJS: Filling a Table using an itemArray

Tags: javascript, gojs

I have a template which looks like this (I am also using jQuery, therefore our GraphObject.make is not `$` but `_`):

```
_(go.Panel, 'Table', {
      itemTemplate: itemTemplate(_)
    },
    new go.Binding('itemArray', 'items')
)
```

Of course that part is not the whole template, I only include the snippet that matters.

What I want to do now is to make an `itemTemplate(_)` that returns practically one row after the other (depending on how much Elements are in the `items` Array.

So I tried having an `itemTemplate()` like this

```
itemTemplate = function(_) {
  return _(
      go.Panel,
      'Horizontal',
      {
        margin: 2
        col: 1
      },
      new go.Binding('row','row')
      _(
        go.Shape,
        'Rectangle',
        {
          stretch: go.GraphObject.Horizontal,
          height: 5
        }
      ),
      _(
        go.TextBlock,
        {
          margin: 2
        },
        new go.Binding('text', 't')
      )
  );
};
```

Here I got to a sudden realisation. With this method I would need to return 2 Panels in order to get the expected output.

If anyone wonders why there is a Binding on row, I got that covered using a callback in the `go.Binding` above, looking like this:

```
new go.Binding('itemArray', 'items',
        function(d) {
          for (i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
            d[i].row = i;
          }
          return d;
        }
      )
```

So here my Question: Is it possible to have a wrapper Panel around the itemTemplate? Like so?

- Panel : Table

  - Panel : No row, No col

    - Panel : row: 1, col: 1
    - Panel : row: 1, col: 2
  - NextPanel : No row No col

Or is it possible to return two seperate templates, for each column?

Or is there another solution which I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the **Panel.itemTemplate** can be a **Panel** of type **TableRow**.  Then each of the elements of this panel can have its column set appropriately.  The row is set automatically.

See the discussion and examples at http://gojs.net/latest/intro/itemArrays.html

Comment: Little offtopic, but I had it in my question although I didn't know if it was right.
When I have `go.Binding("itemArray", "items", function(d){})`
What does the d in the function refer to? The Array as a whole or one index of the Array (`items` or `items[i]`)?

Comment: The argument to the conversion function there would be the value of `nodedata.items`.

Comment: By the way, it's generally undesirable to have side-effects in conversion functions.  You don't know how often or when they will be called.